# Action Send Get Extra File Path

Tags: android

Trying to extract file path from send action:

```
<data android:mimeType="*/*" />
```

Here is activity:

```
  Uri contentUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
                if (contentUri != null) {
                    String pathUri = contentUri.toString();
                    if (pathUri.contains("file://")) {
                        path = contentUri.getPath();
                    }
                }
                if(path==null) {
                    if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
                        path = Constant.getRealPathFromURI(this, (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM));
                    } else if (type.startsWith("video/")) {
                        path = Constant.getRealPathFromURI(this, (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM));
                    }
                }

                if (path == null && intent.getData() != null) {
                    path = intent.getData().getPath();
                }
                if (path == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "None uri !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

1. Always getting null path except 'image/*' and 'video/*".
   on: **Essential PH-1** device
2. Working all fine on: **Lenovo Vibe K5 Note**

Is not bullet proof code for all devices? anything wrong with code?
Is there any universal way to extract send action file path without being worried about it's mimetype?

**Edit:**

```
  public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i see no send action. Or filter.

Comment: And why would you need a file path if you have a nice content scheme uri?

Comment: I need file path for upload purpose also file name is mandatary

Comment: I'm not quite sure what is issue with some devices

Comment: Uploads can be done from a content scheme too. And display name can always be determined.

Comment: I'm not quit sure what your issue is. And why you would need a file path to upload.

Comment: Can you tell me how to determine file name then?

Comment: I'm using python script on server side

Comment: Show the code with which you try to determine the path. You use .DATA ,there i think. Adapt the code for .NAME or .DISPLAY_NAME. Sorry dont know exact from memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163173/discussion-between-ashish-sahu-and-greenapps).

Comment: No. Please suply the info i asked for.

Comment: please check first one (below "Here is activity" title) that's the code I'm using for determine the path

Comment: My god... Whats in your mind? Where is the code for getRealPathFromURI() ? Thats where you try to determine the path.

Comment: I see. this is very common so I did't mentioned please check now

Comment: I repeat: `You use .DATA ,there i think. Adapt the code for .NAME or .DISPLAY_NAME. Sorry dont know exact from memory.`. Why didnt you confirm/comment? Now write a functiion `getDisplayNameFromUri()`.

Comment: Why did you remove the content resolver code opening an inputstream? That was the way to go.

Comment: You're note getting it . I clearly mentioned in my question. Image and video uri path working fine. Why you're looking for that part.  path is null except for image & video mime.

Comment: Yes i know. That is to be expected. You are number #12345 encountering this. You can read about that here about every day. Now if you get what i tried to tell you you write a getDisplayNameFromUri() function. Your problem has been solved here already a hundred times. I just try to push you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you. I will check.